# existance of a compact set

Tags: measure-theory

Let  $\mu$ be a measure with a positive singular part in a complete separable metric space, Can there exist a compact set with Lebesgue measure zero but $\mu(K)>0$?Thanks for any help.

Comment: the lebegue measure of the real line, seen as a measure on $\mathbb C$?

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my question, Thanks for your reply though.

Comment: the same as before still holds, since $[0,1]$ has measure 0 on $\mathbb C$, but the lebesgue measure of the real line has $\mu([0,1]) = 1$

Comment: The Lebesgue measure of the Real line seen as a measure on $\mathbb C$ has a positive singular part? Could you explain a little bit, anyway?

Comment: Thanks! Is it true for any complete, separable metric space?

Comment: What is the "Lebesgue measure" for a generic complete, separable metric space?

Comment: We can think of $\mathbb R^n$, only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From now on, we indicate by $\lambda_n$ the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^n$. If you are looking for singular measures of $\mathbb R^n$, then

- For $n=1$ you can take the [Cantor measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_distribution) $\mu$, that is a singular probability measure whose support is the Cantor set $K$. It is known that $K$ is compact, $\lambda_1(K)=0$, but $\mu(K) = 1$.
- For $n>1$, let $v\in \mathbb R^n$ be a generic non-zero vector. Call $L$ The line generated by $v$, and notice that it is a copy of $\mathbb R$, with $\lambda_n(L) =0$. 
  Consider the singular measure $\mu$ that behaves like $\lambda_1$ on $L$, meaning that
  $$\mu(U) = \lambda_1(U\cap L)$$ 
  for every measurable set $U\subset \mathbb R^n$. This is a singular measure. Since $L$ is closed in $\mathbb R^n$, every compact $K\subset L$ is also a compact for $\mathbb R^n$. You can then find a compact (like $[0,1]$) inside $L$ such that $$\mu(K) >0,\qquad \lambda_n(K)\le \lambda_n(L)=0.$$